# Exception logged when throwing it myself, not when thrown from async method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, exception, async-await

Consider the following ASP.NET WebAPI controller

```cs
public async Task Post(MyModel model)
{
    try
    {
        await _fooBarService.DoStuff(model.Input);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error("Something happened! Whoah!", ex);

        var error = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        error.Content = new StringContent("Nice error message.");
        throw new HttpResponseException(error);
    }
}
```

Which calls a method in a class (`_fooBarService`), which looks like this:

```cs
public async Task DoStuff(string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot be null", nameof(input));

    var response = await _restClient.Put("uri", new BazRequest {input = input});

    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        _logger.Error("Something awful happened.");
        throw new HttpResponseException(response);
    }
}
```

If I supply an empty `input`, and the `ArgumentException` is thrown, the logger picks it up and logs it nicely, as expected. However, if the `_restClient` throws an exception, the error is *not* logged. However, the end user *still gets the "Nice error message" string*, which indeed means that the code block is executed.

If I try-catch and log things inside the `_restClient`, the log is appended as expected.

I suppose this has to do with the `Put(..)` method being async and awaited, but I can't really grasp exactly why since the rest of the catch-block is executed no matter where the Exception comes from.

For what it's worth, the `_logger` is just a very thin wrapper around log4net.

Anyone?

Comment: What you describe isn't possible. If the second line of code in the catch block executed, then the first line did, too.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought too. But it does really happen. I kindof thought that it might be related to the exception bubbling up from an async method being executed on another thread or something, and that the logging framework for some reason then ignored it/crashed/whatever. But since I'm awaiting it and the correct text is returned, that kindof doesn't make sense either... (And the text comes from a translated resource provider in the real code, so other code inside the catch block is indeed called..)

Comment: Please post a minimal, reproducible example, so that others can debug it. (I'm willing to bet that you'll find the problem somewhere else in the code while you're reducing the example).

Comment: I've already thought of it. Might probably happen sometime during the weekend. (And I really hope you're completely right).

Comment: ...and obviously, I can't really reproduce it with a minimal solution either. I'll have a few more looks on the real deal on monday.